# translate luminance to an rgb array

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to translate luminance (an N x M x 1 array) to an rgb array (N x M x 3).

The idea is to use the rgb array to get an rgba array for `imshow()`. The result I'm looking for is identical to what I'd get just feeding the luminance array to `imshow()`, but it gives me control over alpha. Is there some simple function kicking around to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some useful things which you can use in matplotlib to achieve what you want.

You can easily take a collection of numbers, and given an appropriate normalisation and colormap, turn those into rgba values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define a norm which scales data from the range 20-30 to 0-1
norm = plt.normalize(vmin=20, vmax=30)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('hot')
```

With these you can do some useful stuff:

```
>>> # put data in the range 0-1 
>>> norm([20, 25, 30])
masked_array(data = [ 0.   0.5  1. ],
             mask = False,
             fill_value = 1e+20)

# turn numbers in the range 0-1 into colours defined in the cmap
>>> cmap([0, 0.5, 1])
array([[ 0.0416   ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  1.       ],
       [ 1.       ,  0.3593141,  0.       ,  1.       ],
       [ 1.       ,  1.       ,  1.       ,  1.       ]])
```

Is this what you meant, or were you trying to do something else?

Comment: exactly what I was trying to do... somehow I missed trying `cmap.__call__`

Comment: Yes, that's the big problem with making objects callable. Glad it helped.